# What is Oracle Database Vault and how does it work?

Tags: oracle

I am new in oracle database.I am following oracle official site for learning oracle database vault.But i am not satisfied yet.Please help me for getting a preliminary knowledge about oracle database vault

Thanks in advance

Comment: Database Vault is a high end security product, designed to prevent users with privileged access (i.e. DBAs) using their powers for nefarious means.  DV is a chargeable extra on the Enterprise Edition license, and so expensive.  It really isn't something a beginner will come across.

Answer (score 1):

The official Oracle white paper [Oracle Database Vault with
Oracle Database 12c](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/database-vault/database-vault-wp-12c-1896142.pdf), provides a very good high-level overview of the functionality it provides. To be honest, you're not really going to find a better source of material.

Start with that, then read all of the documentation that is linked from the [product home page](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/security/db-vault.html).

There's a fair number of blogs that discuss initial installation and examples of use. Google is your friend.